# Remote Debugging Flask app with Pycharm, Vagrant, Apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask, vagrant, pycharm

I have a Windows computer running vagrant with an ubuntu virtual machine. 
The ubuntu virtual machine has a Flask app running on apache with mod_wsgi.
I've also setup PyCharm to use Vagrant as my remote python interpreter.

I can debug a script fine but I can't seem to find a way to debug the actual flask app which is running.

Vagrant has the code folder shared and forwards port 80 => 8080

I can access my flask app in chrome by going to 127.0.0.1:8080 in Windows.

I've also tried to follow the PyCharm guide by copying the pyhton-debug.egg and adding the following to my **init**.py file

```html
if __name__ =='__main__':
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, threaded=True)

 import sys
 sys.path.append('/home/vagrant/code/Flask-App/pycharm-debug.egg')

 import pydevd
 pydevd.settrace('0.0.0.0', port=8080, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason my `import pydevd` didn't seem to work properly so I used `easy_install` to install the egg and it seems to be OK.

I also had to change the IP address to the IP address from my virtual machine to my Windows machine and use these settings in the debug configuration.

so my `__init__.py` file has:

```
import pydevd

pydevd.settrace(
    '10.0.2.2', 
    port=80, 
    stdoutToServer=True, 
    stderrToServer=True
)
```